# Normal Baking Is going wrong

Tags: modeling, rendering, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have tried countless amount of times and I have yet to properly bake normal maps, it's either not capturing the details from the high poly, or- it does but the normal capture looks bad, It is a very simple procedure but I am somehow having all sorts of trouble
I tried tweaking the max ray distance/Extrusion and still no good results, Even a cage wouldn't work.
I thought I was doing something wrong but I followed a simple tutorial for example, even with the same object and still having issues.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your surface is *really* flat and not bumpy ? It would explain why your normal map looks messed up.

Comment: yes, as you can see in the demonstration, my object is nothing but a simple door, and its frame.
I even made sure that I only have 1 bevel segment in the modifier for the low-poly so I don't have any baking issues

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/